# Mail not sent by node mailer

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs, nodemailer

I am trying to send mail when we click the mail icon of respective id. But I am not able to send the mail.
First I click the icon, it redirects to another ejs file for sending email and then the email is sent from there. Here the mail is not sent so can anyone please help?
Thank you

mail.ejs

```
<form action="/send-email" method="POST">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" name="to">
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" name="from" id="from">
     </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" id="subject">
      </div>

   <div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="">Send</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Controller.js

```
router.get('/donation/mail/:emailid', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('mail', {email: req.query.emailid});
})

router.post('/send-email', function (req, res) {
  var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    port:425,
      auth: {
          // should be replaced with real sender's account
          user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
          pass: 'gmailpassword'
      }
    }));

  var mailOptions = {
      // should be replaced with real recipient's account
        from:'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        to :  req.param.email,
        subject : req.body.subject,
        text : req.body.text

  };
  transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});

res.redirect("/donation");
});
```

I have allowed my gmail account to access non secure app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mail not send by nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221107/mail-not-send-by-nodemailer)

Comment: is there any error? Are you sure that your gmail account allow other apps to send email?

Comment: Yes,It allows and showing not defined in cmd